# How to modify my Python Slack Bolt Socket mode code to reload automatically during any code changes

Tags: python, uvicorn, slack-bolt

I have the following Python code which works fine using the Web Socket mode. When I type a slash command (`/hello-socket-mode`) on my Slash application then it very well invokes my method, `handle_some_command()`:-

```
import os
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

# Install the Slack app and get xoxb- token in advance
app = App(token="<bot token>")


# Add functionality here
@app.command("/hello-socket-mode")
def handle_some_command(ack, body, logger):
    ack()
    print('testing slash command')
    logger.info(body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create an app-level token with connections:write scope
    handler = SocketModeHandler(app,"<app token>")
    handler.start()
```

Since I'm in the development phase of my Slack app, I want to add reload functionality to this backend code of the web socket such that it reloads automatically whenever there is a change in the code. I tried to add `uvicorn` here but with that, I stopped getting invocation to my backend method, `handle_some_command()`whenever I tried to enter the slash command in the my slack application. I created a separate Python script called run.py with following code:-

```
from uvicorn import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, reload=True, log_level="info")
```

And then executed, `python run.py` to run my app using `uvicorn` to reload whenever there is a code change. It is not working at all, I'm not getting any slash command invocation to my backend code now.
I just need some way of reload and not necessarily `uvicorn` here. I would appreciate it if someone could please guide me on this to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this will work; you may delete fastapi dependency if not needed when  development finished

```
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
from slack_bolt.app import App

# Set enviornment vars
BOT_TOKEN = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
APP_TOKEN = os.environ["SLACK_APP_TOKEN"]
SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ["SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET"]

# Load Slack Bolt
app = App(token=BOT_TOKEN, signing_secret=SIGNING_SECRET)

# Load FastAPI
api = FastAPI()

# Load Slack bolt handlers
# Action().add_to(bolt)
SocketModeHandler(app, APP_TOKEN).connect()



@app.message("hello")
def message_hello(message, say):
    say(f"Hey there <@{message['user']}>!")

# Load FastAPI endpoints
@api.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"OK"}
```

And call this code like this:

```
bash -c 'uvicorn app.main:api --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000 --log-level warning'
```